# Postgres JSONB function to key an array of objects, by a field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is there a pure Postgres approach to turning a JSONB array like:

`[{"id": 1, "name": "Dom" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Bass" }]`

into

`{ 1: {"id": 1, "name": "Dom" }, 2: { "id": 2, "name": "Bass" } }`

I.e. same as Lodash doing:

`_.keyBy(arr, 'id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function:

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_key_by(jsonb, text)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(elem->>$2, elem)
    from jsonb_array_elements($1) as arr(elem)
$$;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26b12a1e192a6edb28b36ac156e7f8e0)